# I want to center 2 images in a responsive way

Tags: html, css

I want to center the two images in the middle of the screen but don't want them touching eachother. This is for a school project and i'm not very experienced in HTML and CSS so if you could help me out it would be amazing! My teacher told me to create those display tables but i dind't understand how they work so if you could also give me a hint on how it works I would appreciate that! Thanks in advance! If you need me to send any other information please tell me as I'm not sure what to put in there other than what I told above.

HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Correia e Figueiredo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css"/>
        </head>
    <body>
    <div id="imagens">
        <div id="Morph1" class="images">
            <a href="figueiredo.html"> <img src="images/Morph1.png"> </a>
            </div>
            <div id="Morph2" class="images">
            <a href="figueiredo.html"> <img src="images/Morph2.png"> </a>
            </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
`*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    background-color: beige;
}

#imagens {
    display: table;
}

#Morph1 {
    display: table-cell;
}


#Morph2 {
    display: table-cell;
}

.images a img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.images {
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
}`
```

Comment: I think you can define margins for .images:
 `.images::first-child {
    margin: 0 2px 0 auto;
}
 .images::last-child {
    margin: 0 auto 0 2px;
}` 
It has to work if you're placing two images

Comment: You can also it by using a bit of janky flexbox ruling and margins on the images, but it seems there are better options suggested already.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
#imagens {width:100%;}
.images {padding: 10px} /*delete text-align: center*/
#Morph1 {text-align: right;}
#Morph2 {text-align: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `padding` on both `#Morph1` and `#Morph2`, will do the job.

Just like:

```
#Morph1 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
}


#Morph2 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Look at the snippet below:

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    background-color: beige;
}

#imagens {
    display: table;
}

#Morph1 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
}


#Morph2 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.images a img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.images {
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagens">
        <div id="Morph1" class="images">
            <a href="figueiredo.html"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400"> </a>
            </div>
            <div id="Morph2" class="images">
            <a href="figueiredo.html"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400"> </a>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
 .img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 30px; 
}
#images{
   text-align:center;
}
```

---

```
<div id="images">
<a href="#">
<img class="img" border="0" alt="" src="https://wallpapers.pub/web/wallpapers/birds-water-spray-wallpaper/3840x2160.jpg"/></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img class="img" border="0" alt="" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" /></a></div>
```

link:-https://jsfiddle.net/ghnthrbn/